# Javamail in Servlet doesn't work

Tags: java, email, servlets, jakarta-mail

I want to use Javamail to send a mail in my Java Web-App. For first trials I use the tutorial on this site: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/jeetutorials/sendingemail/

I copied the code word for word. I have the latest Javamail jar file in my buildpath. And I have a google mail so the gmail server as a default is cool for me.

So my code looks exactly like the code in the link.

When I try to send a mail I allways get the error that the EmailServlet is not available. But If I try a simple code file in a doGet or doPost, it works! It just doesn't work with that code.

I also tried other tutorials, but the problem was always the same.

Any idea what the problem can be?

Thanks!

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Handwerker</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you check the server logs - if there is any error when your web app is deployed. Also very importantly have you added the javamail jar file in the WEB-INF/lib folder?

Comment: Can you share more details ? Please share your servlet and web.xml

Comment: I added the Web.xml code in the top post. For the deployment and URL pattern I use the automate deployment decriptor (or whatever it is called) from Eclipse. And it works with every single servlet.

It even works with this servlet when I start a doGet Method.

I also tried to add the Servlet into the Web.xml manually. It didn't change anything.

the javamail jar (mail.jar) is in my lib folder. All javamail plugins are in my lib folder. And even the activation.jar that is mentioned in many tutorials is in my lib folder.

Comment: There's no way to diagnose anything with the information provided in the question.

Comment: Yes, we really need details about the error.  Where exactly do you get the error about the servlet not being available, and what exactly does the error say?  What error messages do you find in the log file?  Have you tried restarting the server?  What server are you using?

Comment: It's a Tomcat Server. The error is that the servlet is not available. If I write code into the doGet or the doPost method everything works fine. If I use the mail code from the link in my post, the servlet is not available anymore.

But I tried something else now. I tried apache commons instead of just javamail and that works fine.